# How do I make the icon in the middle of the button?

Tags: html, button

So I'm very new to HTML and when creating a button with an icon using some guides, it ended up looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcGY9.png).

The Code is this:

```css
.button {
    border: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #5865f2;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}

.button-icon {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.button-text {
    padding: 10px 18px;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">
    <i class="button-icon material-icons">discord</i>
    <span class="button-text">TheF1ng3r</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, you missed the `display: flex` on your `.button` selector

```css
.button {
    display: flex;
    .....
    align-items: center;
}
```

**Note:**
if you want to use the CSS `align-items` property you must include `display: flex` on your CSS code on the same selector.